# Bot Framework Composer: How to duplicate dialogs?

Tags: bot-framework-composer

is there a way to duplicate (copy/paste) a dialog in Bot Framework Composer?

Sometimes I want to reuse the conversational flow of an already existing dialog in a new dialog like a skeleton and just modify it, so I don't have to click together the components again and again. Is there a way to do it?

BR Johannes

Answer (score 0):

To do copy and paste you can do like below and you can check attached images.

1. To select elements hold ctrl and click mouse.
2. Click Edit menu
3. Click + on dialog flow where you wants to paste copied elements.
4. Paste option will appear, click to paste.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An alternative to holding CTRL and clicking is simply to left-click hold and draw a box around the actions that you want to copy (or cut).  If they don't fit on screen, zoom out first.

Answer (score 0):

For copying between bots, you can do the following with Bot Framework Composer closed: -
Navigate to the bot's source-code folder.
In there is a folder called "dialogs".
In there is one folder for each of your dialogs.  Simply copy the folder(s) that you want
Navigate to the other bot and paste into that one's dialog folder.

When you load the new bot in Composer, it'll have the pasted-in dialogs.